# query on array in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

hi friends i am a new developer to java and android,

in my app i am using sax parser to getting the values of a particular tag. i have stored all those values in an Array. When i printed it in my log cat it appears to be as follows.

```
[s,d,f,g,h,h,j,q,k,k...............]
```

Now my problem is, in another activity i used to get a dynamic value, if the value is `7` i want the seventh value stored in the array list.

How to do this, please guide me friends....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn how activities can share data through intents' extra. Read [anddev](http://andbook.anddev.org/files/andbook.pdf) book, page 58.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

Pass your indexed value from your current activity

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this,FeedDetailActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("INDEX_VALUE","YOUR_VALUE"); //in your case it would be YOUR_VALUE -> arr[i]
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

And following is the way to access value in another activity

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
final String indexValue = bundle.getString("INDEX_VALUE");
```

Hope this helps !!!